# Database of cancer cells

Tags: cancer, database, growth

I am looking for a database(or any kind of information source) of cancer cells, which has information about the speed of reproduction of these cells, how fast they grow, etc.

So I could make my simulation as accurate as possible, as close to reality as possible (I am working on developing a software that simulates how cancerous cells spread).

**Edit**

> Are you interested in growth rates in culture or in vivo (e.g. tumours)

Okay, I am a *noob* in biology, so let me explain it like that.
I am using Voronoi graphs for simulation, so I think that I am interested in tumor level, how each cell interacts with each other, and thus how fast can cancerous cells overpopulate healthy(or other cancerous) cells.

Comment: I suggest making your title more specific. You should at least mention proliferation, growth rate or a similar term.

Comment: Are you interested in growth rates in culture or in vivo (e.g. tumours)

Answer (score 5):

The National Cancer Institute (NCI) has a list of doubling times for a variety of commonly used cell lines, see 
https://dtp.cancer.gov/discovery_development/nci-60/cell_list.htm

I my experience, these doubling times are quite stable/reproducible, provided that cells are kept in standard culture conditions. While doubling times differ a lot between cell lines, they are also very different in size, and larger cells tend to have longer doubling times so that the *biomass* growth rate is actually rather similar between lines.

*Note:* these doubling times refer to cell culture conditions. Actual tumors *in vivo* grow much more slowly, due to lack of nutrients, suppression by immune cells, and what not. Estimating cell growth rates in tumors is a much more complicated business, and I don't know of any database for that.